# overflow обрезает изображения за контейнером слайдера

Tags: css, overflow, hidden

сделал свой первый слайдер: несколько div с шириной 100% в линию, с background-image-ами. Прокрутка работает путем изменения позиции родительского контейнера(, содержащего div-ы с изображениями)-transform('translateX(position)') /*position=100% или 200% или 300% и т.д.*/ Все работает, если overflow:visible, если overflow:hidden, то показывает только первое изображение, остальных нет-пустое пространство. Уже думаю сделать с помощью другого метода(display:none/block или переставлять активный класс на текущее изображение.) Просто интересно для понимания если применять overflow:hidden хвост слайдера обрезается навсегда или оставшиеся изображения должны сдвигаться? и как сделать так, чтобы работало с таким подходом, если это возможно?

```
HTML:
<button class="button prev">prev</button>
<button class="button next">next</button>
<div class="sliderline">
    <div class="sldrimg one"></div>
    <div class="sldrimg two"></div>
    <div class="sldrimg img3"></div>
    <div class="sldrimg four"></div>
</div>
CSS:
sliderline{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
sldrimg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 475px;
    background-size: cover;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
JS:
let position = 0
document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', function(){
    const sliderline = document.querySelector('.sliderline')
    let offset = 100
    position -= offset
    sliderline.style.transform = `translate(${position}%,0)`
})

document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', function(){
    const sliderline = document.querySelector('.sliderline')
    let offset = 100
    position += offset
    sliderline.style.transform = `translate(${position}%,0)`
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

необходимо задать overflow:hidden родительскому классу, например:

```
HTML
<div class="slider">
            <button class="button prev">prev</button>
            <button class="button next">next</button>

            <div class="sliderline">
                <div class="sldrimg one"></div>
                <div class="sldrimg two"></div>
                <div class="sldrimg img3"></div>
                <div class="sldrimg four"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
CSS
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.sliderline{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
```